# Biblatex: How to get the information in note field

Tags: biblatex, citing

I use the following format for my bibliography.

```
@thesis {RefKey,
AUTHOR = {LastName, F.},
 TITLE = {Thesis Title},
  NOTE = {Ph.D. thesis},
SCHOOL = {University},
  YEAR = {Year},
}
```

I can receive the informations *AUTHOR*, *TITLE*, *SCHOOL* and *YEAR* by using `\citeauthor{RefKey}`, `\citetitle{RefKey}`, `\citelist{RefKey}{institution}` and `\citeyear{RefKey}`. However, I am **not** able to get the information in *NOTE* field by `\citelist{RefKey}{note}`. Also in `@article` and `@book`, the same problem occurs. Is there a way to receive the data in *NOTE* field?

Comment: Just as a general comment: by design the way to specify the type of a thesis is the `type` field, not the "abuse" of the note field.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `citefield` command.

```
\citefield{RefKey}{note}
```

Comment: How can I know when I should use `\citelist` or `\citefield`?

Comment: @bkarpuz I suggest you read the manual (section 3.7.7 *Low-level commands* is about these commands). Basically, `biblatex` has different data types, and those citation commands corresponds to these types. `\citename` is for *name lists* (e.g. author, editor), `\citelist` is for *literal lists* (e.g. publisher, location), `\citefield` is for *fields* (e.g. title, note, date, url).