# How to extract BibTeX entries (as DOI, abstract, etc.)

Tags: biblatex, bibentry

I want to automate personal reading notes generation, I'd like to be able to automatically extract a field's content from a BibTeX entry (other than `year` or `author`).

E.g. given a BibTeX entry

```
@article{einstein05,
   author={Albert Einstein},
   title={Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper},
   abstract={Interesting article, which claims that time is relative.},
   journal={Annalen der Physik und Chemie},
   volume={17},
   year={1905},
   pages={891--921}
}
```

I want to have a macro in my TeX file (e.g. `\citeabstract`) that will return the string `Interesting article, which claims that time is relative.` (the same for DOI, etc.)

I've found the `\printfield` command that might help me, but I'm not smart enough to know how to use it.

I don't know if it has any influence on the answer, but I'm using BibLaTeX+BibTeX.

Comment: You could use `\citefield[<prenote>][<postnote>]{<key>}[<format>]{<field>}`, so in your case that would be `\citefield{einstein05}{abstract}` to cite the `abstract` field and `\citefield{einstein05}{doi}` to cite the DOI (there are `\citename` and `\citelist` to cite name (lists) and lists as well). Of course you could wrap that up in a new command. The other way is to define a new command like this: `\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeabstract}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\printfield{abstract}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}`.

Comment: @moewe `\citefield` is the command I was looking for. Thank you !

Comment: See also [Biblatex: How to get the information in note field](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/122877/35864)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have at least two options to achieve this.

### `\citefield` and friends

We can use `\citefield` and friends to access any field of any bibliography entry using the

```
\citefield[<prenote>][<postnote>]{<key>}[<format>]{<field>}
```

syntax (so `\citefield` does indeed work like your normal cite command).

One needs to be aware, however, that in `biblatex` what one would naively call data field comes in three flavours (1) `field` - a field containing one item such as `title`, `journaltitle` or `doi`, also range field such as `pages`, (2) `list` a list of items such as `publisher` (one book might be published by quite some publishers, apparently), `address` (the publisher might have an office in New York and one in Berlin), and (3) name lists for `author`, `editor` and the like. As these three types need different handling, there are `\citefield`, `\citelist` and `\citename` (see §3.7.7 *Low-level Commands*, p. 91 of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)).
So we need to choose the right `\cite*`-command for the job, if it is not clear which one to choose, the `biblatex` documentation lists all the available fields (in the wider sense) in §2.2 *Entry Fields* starting at page 13 down to page 30.

So you would use `\citefield{einstein05}{abstract}` and `\citefield{einstein05}{doi}` to cite the abstract and DOI of your example entry, but `\citename{einstein05}{author}` (which does essentially the same as `\citeauthor` here) to display the author's name.

Note that the `\cite*` commands by default (i.e. if the optional argument `<format>` is empty) use the generic formats `citename`, `citelist` and `citelist` for their output regardless of the field you intend to print. So you will have to give the format explicitly if it deviates from the plain `cite...` formats. If you want the DOI formatted in its usual `doi` format you need to issue `\citefield{einstein05}[doi]{doi}`. See the discussion in [biblatex: clickable doi outside the reference section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/319684/35864). This limitation (or feature) goes away if you use the second method described below.

### A custom command

If you do need to cite the `abstract` field quite often, you might want to save you some typing (especially of those pesky curly braces), you could then declare a `\citeabstract` command like this

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeabstract}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\printfield{abstract}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

and use it like `\citeabstract{einstein05}`.

This command will always pick up the appropriate format for the printed field in the appropriate context. Of course this can be explicitly overridden by the optional argument to `\printfield`.

Comment: How do I get the key which is used to indicate the bibliographic entry, such as `[Ein05]` or `[1]`?

Comment: @xxx--- `\cite{<key>}`? If you need the label for use in `\DeclareCiteCommand` then the answer will depend on your style. I suggest you ask a new question explaining your use case in more detail (ideally with an MWE).