# \citefield to include abstract from BibTeX file

Tags: macros, biblatex, bibtex

I am trying to use `\citefield{soure1}{abstract}` to include an abstract from my BibTeX file in my document. But, I always receive the message

> Undefined control sequence.\citefield

Here is an MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{authoryear,
title = {title},
author = {XY},
journal = {XY},
volume = {119},
pages = {100},
year = {2015},
url = {http://www.url.com},
abstract = {long abstract.}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=2cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english,german]{babel}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\pagestyle{myheadings}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-2\baselineskip,
  afterskip=1\baselineskip]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-1\baselineskip,
  afterskip=0.5\baselineskip]{subsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-1\baselineskip,
  afterskip=.5\baselineskip]{subsubsection}
\newenvironment{newabstract}

\begin{document}

\begin{newabstract}
  \citefield{authoryear}{abstract}
\end{newabstract}

\section*{Group A}
\subsection*{\cite{authoryear} \\ \href{http://www.url.com}{title} }

\bibliography{authoryear} 
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks like this is a biblatex command. You didn't declare the use of the biblatex package in your document, but you're using natbib instead.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Where did you find the `\citefield` macro? (It isn't a natbib macro for sure.) Apart from that you document needs to be reworked a little: Look up the syntax for `\newenvironment`, `\bibliography` and `\bibliographystyle`.

Comment: @Ruben as stated in my comment above, `\citefield` is a `biblatex` command.

Comment: @JMP, that was just a subtle hint towards beeing aware of where one gets macros and its associated information from.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I found the \citefield command under a similar question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207591/how-to-extract-bibtex-entries-as-doi-abstract-etc

Comment: I tried to use the biblatex package (and deleted the natbib macro) but than my citations didn't work anymore and the \citefield command didn't work neither :)

Answer (score 3):

`\citefield` is a `biblatex` command. You may be able to get away with `usebib`; check the documentation for more information.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{authoryear,
title = {title},
author = {XY},
journal = {XY},
volume = {119},
pages = {100},
year = {2015},
url = {http://www.url.com},
abstract = {long abstract.}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{usebib}

\newbibfield{abstract}
\bibinput{\jobname}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
\usebibentry{authoryear}{abstract}
\end{abstract}

\section*{Group A}
\subsection*{\cite{authoryear} \\ \href{http://www.url.com}{title} }

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help! But with usebib it is not possible to access a separate bibfile, is that correct?

Comment: @C.S.KIT You can give as many `\bibinput` commands as you like