# \citefield{key}{author} and \citefield{key}{journal} of biblatex do not work

Tags: biblatex

Consider following MWE:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage{biblatex} % version 3.3 with biber 2.4 (TexLive 2015)
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{example,
  author  = {AUTHOR A, AUTHOR B},
  journal = {NAME OF JOURNAL},
  title   =  {NAME OF PAPER},
  year    = {2016},
  volume  = {12},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item \citefield{example}{author}
  \item \citefield{example}{journal}
  \item \citefield{example}{title}
  \item \citefield{example}{year}
  \item \citefield{example}{volume}
\end{itemize}

\fullcite{example}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see author and journal are not given. What is the problem or is there a bug in this biblatex version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is given here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/207676/8917

Replacing `citefield` with `citename` for entry author. For the entry `journal` one has to use `journaltitle` even though the entry is called `journal` in the bibfile.

```
   \item \citename{example}{author}
   \item \citefield{example}{journaltitle}
```