# Citing multiple fields of bibliography entry

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

Using `\citefield{key}{field}` with BibLatex, it is possible to cite a specific data field of the bibliography entry.

Is it possible to do this with multiple fields, e.g. to use it as new citation style, by combining the field keywords (e.g. `{field1 | field2}`)?

Or is the best way to do this by simply using two `\citefield` commands?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you plan to print multiple fields it is probably best to define a new `\cite*` command. That can even be a good idea if you only plan to print one field, because it can save some typing, see [How to extract BibTeX entries (as DOI, abstract, etc.)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/207591/35864) for example.

You could use something like

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citesomefields}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\printfield{<field1>}%
   \setunit{\addcomma\space}% <- or any other punctuation you'd like: \addperiod, \addspace, ...
   \printfield{<field2>}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

That command can then be used like `\citesomefields{sigfridsson}` and you get to see `<field1>` and `<field2>` of the entry `sigfridsson`. The advantage of this approach is that it handles multiple citations as well as pre- and postnotes.

In this definition we explicitly disable tracking of the "citations" with `\boolfalse{citetracker}\boolfalse{pagetracker}`, this is what happens in the pre-defined `\citeauthor` and `\citetitle` commands as well. If you want to track your "citations" (for example if you want to use the new command as a drop-in replacement for the real `\cite` - which I'm not too fond of, if you want to modify the appearance of citations, modify `\cite` and its output, don't try to come up with a manual solution) just remove the two lines from the pre-code hook above.

Comment: I'd say that if you plan to use the same `\citefield` more than once or twice in your document it is a good idea to make it into a new `\cite*` command with `\DeclareCiteCommand`.