# How to extract multiple BibTeX fields?

Tags: biblatex, citing

I'm trying to cite more than one field (e.g., title, author and year).

I've tried `\citefield` but it doesn't seem to accept more than one field ([How to extract BibTeX entries (as DOI, abstract, etc.)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207591/how-to-extract-bibtex-entries-as-doi-abstract-etc))

Is there something like `\citefield{somepaper2020}{title,author,year}`?

Answer (score 1):

`\citefield` only gives you one field. If you want to access several fields at once, you need to define a custom cite command.

A standard `\...cite` command has the structure

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\atycite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{author:title:year}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

where the bibmacro (here `author:title:year`) does the real work and prints the desired fields and the punctuation between them. For example

```
\newbibmacro*{author:title:year}{%
  \printnames{labelname}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printdate
}
```

Here I used the special fields `labelname` and `labeltitle` that are automatically calculated from the `author`, `editor`, ... fields and from `title`, `shorttitle` etc. instead of `\printnames{author}` and `\printfield{title}`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\newbibmacro*{author:title:year}{%
  \printnames{labelname}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printdate
}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\atycite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{author:title:year}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{sigfridsson}

\atycite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson and Ryde: ‘Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments’, 1998]

---

If this is supposed to come your go-to citation style instead of just a one-off, you may want to make this more advanced and make sure that the command can deal with advanced `biblatex` features like `shorthand`, works together correctly with the bibliography style (and its sorting) etc.