# \citetitle like command for arbitrary field with biblatex/biber

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber

Can I print the string of an arbitrary field with biblatex/biber?

MWE below

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{ref.bib}
  @book{test,
    author    = {J. Doe},
    title     = {Book of something}
    number    = {123}
  }
\end{filecontents}


\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}


\begin{document}

  The author of \cite{test} is \citeauthor{test},
  the number is \citenumber{test} \citenum{test}  % don't work
  
  I would love a command that works for any field like so \citefield{number}{test}
  
  \printbibliography
  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/207591/35864

Comment: Did the linked answer answer your question or did you have trouble implementing the suggestions (if so, it would help if you could describe what you tried and how it did not work for you in more detail).

Comment: I flagged as duplicate.