# Create custom entry and reference fields

Tags: biblatex, cross-referencing, labels, glossary

I am writing a novel and I would like to create a data structure to hold character attributes and be able to reference the values.

I looked into creating custom glossaries, bibtex and datatool structure but I wasn't able to find a suitable method. I would much prefer not creating custom commands and using native latex available functionality.

Example

```
character{emma,
    title = {Emma},
    dateofbirth = {1995-05-10},
    eyecolor = {brown}
}

Emma her eye colour is \ref{emma:eyecolor}.
```

Comment: "Standard LaTeX" does not have a function to do that out of the box. You will have to resort to packages. I'm not sure if `biblatex` is your best bet here, but since you tagged your question `biblatex`, let me say that you can define new data types as described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175776/35864 and that you can extract specific data from entries as shown in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/207591/35864.

Comment: This could be a solution, I tried it but cant get the MWE working. All I see is `[se:l3help]` on the page, not its contents.

Comment: Do you really need to use external tools to manage this? It's easy to set up a data structure like your example using `expl3` property lists. Also it's not too difficult to parse JSON input in LuaTeX. See [Ways to parse JSON in LaTeX?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/222604).

Comment: I have not used expl3 before and not sure how it works, I dont want to make it too complicated, not for myself but also others

Comment: If you want to use the `biblatex` solution you need to compile your document with Biber. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 for background and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 for help on getting your editor to run Biber for you. I don't necessarily think `biblatex` is the best approach here. You don't need all features of bibliographies and citations and the overhead is probably not worth it here.

Comment: I'm not clear what you're asking for. You don't want custom commands and you want only native LaTeX functionality, but you've rejected the suggestion to use the most suitable native LaTeX functionality. What would an acceptable answer look like, given that `\ref{}` doesn't do what you'd like it to?

Comment: This question has been closed (which I don't agree with) but here is an `expl3` example of what I had in mind in my previous comment. I don't think `biblatex` is the right tool for what you want to do. [Programming with LaTeX -- Add names and characteristics](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/324224)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with others that a bibtex database probably is not the best way. One alternative that you may explore is put the data in a R data frame, that can be easily integrated with LaTeX text in several ways.

Here a MWE showing only some of these ways:

(note: if you do not have idea of what is R/knitr, save the file as `mwe.Rnw` to compile it with RStudio, or alternatively save it as  `mwe.Rtex` to compile it on line in Overleaf.)

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

<<data,echo=FALSE,results="asis">>=
df <- data.frame(
    name=c("Negan","Rick Grimes","Maggie Greene"),
    date = c("1995-05-10","1995-05-13","2005-05-13"),
    eyecolor = c("brown","blue","green"),
    rol = c("evil","hero","survivor"),
    zombies=c(502,834,254)
)

row.names(df) <-  c("negan","rick","maggie") # nick names  


library(xtable)
library(knitr)
print(xtable(df, caption="Example characters to start walking, but alive."), booktabs=TRUE)

df$date <-  as.Date(df$date)

@

I am 
\Sexpr{df["negan","name"]}. Main characters are 
\Sexpr{combine_words(df$name)}. 
\Sexpr{df$name[1]} have  
\Sexpr{df$eyecolor[1]} eyes and born in 
\Sexpr{format(df$date[1], format="%Y")} 
and he is the 
\Sexpr{df["negan","rol"]}, whereas 
\Sexpr{df["rick","name"]} is the  
\Sexpr{df["rick","rol"]} of  
\Sexpr{df["rick","eyecolor"]} eyes and born only 
\Sexpr{df$date[2]-df$date[1]} days later. 
\Sexpr{df["maggie","name"]} was roughly 
\Sexpr{round((df$date[3]-df$date[2])/365.25,0)} years younger and have  
\Sexpr{df[3,3]} eyes. She is a 
\Sexpr{df["maggie","rol"]} survivor of the zombie apocalypse. 
Each character kill an average of
\Sexpr{round(mean(df$zombies),0)} zombies.
\end{document}
```