# Cite publisher in text from BibLaTeX

Tags: biblatex

Suppose I have the following database:

```
@book{croyle2014,
title={Public Update for Drought Response: Groundwater Basins with Potential Water Shortages and Gaps in Groundwater Monitoring},
author={Croyle, William and Gutierrez, David and Ericson, Jon and Alemi, Manucher and Mathis, Dane and Scruggs, Mary},
publisher={California Department of Water Resources},
year={2014},
url={http://www.water.ca.gov/waterconditions/docs/Drought_Response-Groundwater_Basins_April30_Final_BC.pdf},
urldate={2016-09-04}
}
```

I want to cite the book's publisher in my text, that is the *California Department of Water Resources*. I know the `\citeauthor` command, but there is apparently no `\citepublisher` so how can I achieve that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sources.bib}
\begin{document}

The survey was done by \citepublisher{croyle2014}. %Adjust that so that it works.

\end{document}
```

Comment: See also [How to extract BibTeX entries (as DOI, abstract, etc.)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/207591/35864) as well as [Biblatex: How to get the information in note field](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/122877/35864)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\citelist{croyle2014}{publisher}
```

See page 94 of the current manual for details and optional arguments.

If you expect to use this a lot, you can say

```
\DeclareCiteCommand\citepublisher
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}% supplemented from moewe's answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/207676/
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}}
  {\printlist{publisher}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {}
```

[edited to reflect moewe's suggestion, based on code in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/207676/)]

and then write

```
\citepublisher{}
```

For example,

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{croyle2014,
title={Public Update for Drought Response: Groundwater Basins with Potential Water Shortages and Gaps in Groundwater Monitoring},
author={Croyle, William and Gutierrez, David and Ericson, Jon and Alemi, Manucher and Mathis, Dane and Scruggs, Mary},
publisher={California Department of Water Resources},
year={2014},
url={http://www.water.ca.gov/waterconditions/docs/Drought_Response-Groundwater_Basins_April30_Final_BC.pdf},
urldate={2016-09-04}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareCiteCommand\citepublisher
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}% supplemented from moewe's answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/207676/
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}}
  {\printlist{publisher}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {}
\begin{document}

The survey was done by \citelist{croyle2014}{publisher}.

\citepublisher{croyle2014}

\end{document}
```

[image: publisher]

Then you don't have to remember whether `publisher` is a `list` or a `field`. Of course, the definition would need to be a bit more complex if you want lists of publishers formatted correctly, but the above gives the basic template for filling the details out.

Comment: I've just tried it (because I actually thought, it would be correct anyways), you have to change citefield to citelist. Maybe you can adjust your answer in order to not confuse others.

Comment: @OliverBorchert Thanks, I just changed it and then saw your comment. I'd used this myself and forgot you needed something different for `list` fields. Sorry about that. (Reminder to self: it is never that simple!)

Comment: @OliverBorchert In case you'd like to create a `\citepublisher` for convenience, please see edit above.

Comment: In your `\citepublisher` it could be convenient to turn off the citete-tracking features so you don't get an "ibid" (with an ibid style) where you don't expect one. (See for example [How to extract BibTeX entries (as DOI, abstract, etc.)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/207676/35864))

Comment: @OliverBorchert Please see edit for moewe's suggested changes.